# PFQueryTableViewController doesn't find my class

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

The login and signing up process work well in my code, therefore i have an existing User class, but i'm getting this error **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: ' setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: classname)'
First throw call stack:** when i launch the simulator. So i don't understand which class missing or nil, because i've set the User class to query on. (I wanna display the usernames in a list)

```
@interface Contacts ()

@end

@implementation Contacts


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom the table

        // The className to query on
        self.parseClassName = @"User";

        // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
        self.textKey = @"username";

        // The title for this table in the Navigation Controller.
        self.title = @"Title";

        // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

        // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
        self.paginationEnabled = YES;

        // The number of objects to show per page
        self.objectsPerPage = 5;
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
    if (currentUser) {
        NSLog(@"Current user: %@", currentUser.username);
    } else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goLogin" sender:self];
    }

}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - Parse

- (void)objectsDidLoad:(NSError *)error {
    [super objectsDidLoad:error];

    // This method is called every time objects are loaded from Parse via the PFQuery
}

- (void)objectsWillLoad {
    [super objectsWillLoad];

    // This method is called before a PFQuery is fired to get more objects
}


// Override to customize what kind of query to perform on the class. The default is to query for
// all objects ordered by createdAt descending.
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];

    // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
    // and then subsequently do a query against the network.
    if ([self.objects count] == 0) {
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    }

    [query orderByAscending:@"priority"];

    return query;
}



// Override to customize the look of a cell representing an object. The default is to display
// a UITableViewCellStyleDefault style cell with the label being the first key in the object.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"contactCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell
    cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"text"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Priority: %@", [object objectForKey:@"priority"]];

    return cell;
}


/*
 // Override if you need to change the ordering of objects in the table.
 - (PFObject *)objectAtIndex:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 return [objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 }
 */

/*
 // Override to customize the look of the cell that allows the user to load the next page of objects.
 // The default implementation is a UITableViewCellStyleDefault cell with simple labels.
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForNextPageAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NextPage";
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 if (cell == nil) {
 cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 }
 cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
 cell.textLabel.text = @"Load more...";
 return cell;
 }
 */

#pragma mark - Table view data source

/*
 // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
 return YES;
 }
 */

/*
 // Override to support editing the table view.
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
 // Delete the row from the data source
 [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
 }
 else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
 // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
 }
 }
 */

/*
 // Override to support rearranging the table view.
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
 {
 }
 */

/*
 // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
 return YES;
 }
 */

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqual:@"goLogin"]) {
        [segue.destinationViewController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
    }
}
- (IBAction)logoutButton:(id)sender {
    [PFUser logOut];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goLogin" sender:self]; }
@end
```

Comment: Is this tableView getting called programmatically or is it being instantiated via storyboards?

Comment: @Jonathan I'm using storyboards.

Comment: I've made a research on the PFQTVC vs. storyboard topic, and here's the answer: https://parse.com/questions/can-i-use-storyboards-with-pfquerytableviewcontroller. Thnx Jonathan, you gave the idea.

Comment: You're welcome! I actually had the exact same problem as you did and moving over to `initWithCoder:` is what solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the `initWithStyle` method is called? If you're using storyboards, you need to use `initWithCoder` instead of `initWithStyle`.

**Update**

Also, replace

```
    // The className to query on
    self.parseClassName = @"User";
```

with

```
    // The className to query on
    self.parseClassName = @"_User";
```

Comment: The initWithCoder solved the problem, it's running without any errors, but doesn't display any content, only a blank table view. Do you have any idea what could be the problem? The usernames should be displayed.

Comment: Are you using the default cell style, or customized cells? Try putting NSLog(object[@"username"]) in cellForRowAtIndexPath and check that the username actually appears in the console

Comment: Oh, you should use "_User" as the parseClassName instead of "User", as this is a system class and not a custom class

Comment: I'm using the default cells. First i just wanna see something in the cells, it would be a huge success for me. I have to use the underscore for the **self.textKey** to? Because the cells are still empty. I have only one user in the database, but i think the number of the users doesn't matter until there is minimum one.

Comment: No, only for the User class. Did you try the log statement?

Comment: Yes, i tried it. But i've got errors and couldn't run the simulator with this ' - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:NSLog(object[@"username"]) object:(PFObject *)object {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"contactCell";'

Comment: Ok. Create a new question and describe your code and your error messages so more people will look at it than me :-)

Comment: I'll do it. Thnk you for your help again. It would be impossible to learn this stuff without the helpful guys like you.